# Roboguice - Two implementations for one interface

Tags: java, android, dependency-injection, roboguice

My code is like this:

```
interface MyIntreface{
     ...
}

class A implements MyInterface{}     
class B implements MyInterface{}  

class BaseClass{
    @Inject
    MyInterface  instance;
}

class MyFirstClass extends BaseClass{
   ....
}

class MySecondClass extends BaseClass{
   ....
}
```

Now I want to MyFirstClass have implementation A and MySecondClass implementation B. @Named annotations seems not to work in this case. Is there any other robo-solution ?

Answer (score 0):

This use case is impossible to implements using Roboguice. But there are two ways to resolve your problem.

- Implement provider that injects MyFirstClass and MySecondClass and then inject to provider A or B and use setter to set it in created instance
- `class Baclass BaseClass{
       protected abstract MyInterface extractMyInterface();

   } 
   class MyFirstClass extends BaseClass{
       @Inject
       B  instance;
       protected MyInterface extractMyInterface() {
          return instance; 
       }

    }
    class MySecondClass extends BaseClass{
        @Inject
        A  instance;
        protected MyInterface extractMyInterface() {
            return instance;
        } 
    }`

In my opinion the first one (with Provider) is much more cleaner.